# Swift: Do we need to declare a variable before using it?

Tags: swift

I am very new to swift. And I met this problem quite by accident.

This is an example in **The Swift Programming Language(Swift 2.1)**.

```
let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]
var teamScore = 0
for score in individualScores {
    if score > 50 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
print(teamScore)
```

As can be seen, `score` is a variable in the code section above. But it's apparently not declared before using it. I mean, there is no syntax like this:

```
var score: Int
```

or

```
var score = 0
```

I just want to know why, or how to do that, using a variable without declaring its type with `var` syntax.

As the grammar in C++ (Swift is, in some way, similar with C++), it should be "can't be recognized" if the variable has not been declared.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it only exists inside the loop

Comment: In only exists within the loop. Its type is inferred to be the element type of the object that you enumerate over (`Int` since `individualScores` is an `[Int]`). The variable can't be assigned to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`score` is assigned by the `for` loop. Its type is inferred as whatever the element of `individualScores` is. Since `individualScores` is an `Array` of `Int`, or `[Int]`, `score` must be an `Int`. Therefore, you don't need to formally declare its type in this case.

There's similar behavior with closures, where you can name variables without formally declaring them with `let` or `var`. For example:

```
let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]
var teamScore = 0

individualScores.forEach {
    score in
    if score > 50 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}

print(teamScore)
```

Comment: Thank you! As I continued learning it, I find this phenomenon is quite often. Variables used only in **for loop** always use this informal declaration, and they will be meaningless outside the **for loop**, right?

Comment: Yes, only meaningful inside the for loop, just like `i` in: `for(int i=0; i < something; i++){...`.